# PHP Question: how to array_intersect_assoc() recursively

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I want to do this:

```php
$a = array_intersect_assoc(
 array(
  'key1' => array(
   'key2' => 'value2'
  ),
  'key3' => 'value3',
  'key4' => 'value4'
 ),
 
 array(
  'key1' => array(
   'key2' => 'some value not in the first parameter'
  ),
  'key3' => 'another value'
 )
);

var_dump( $a );
```

The printed result is:

```
array
  'key1' => 
    array
      'key2' => string 'value2' (length=6)
```

It's clear that values associated with 'key2' in both arrays are not the same, however `array_intersect_assoc()` still return `'key2' => 'value2'` as the intersected value.

Is this the expected behavior of `array_intersect_assoc()`?

Thanks!

Comment: That's pretty amazing! Especially since `array('key2' => 'value2') == array('key2' => 'some value not in the first parameter') === false`, whereas `array('key2' => 'value2') == array('key2' => 'value2') === true`. I think I speak for many people here when I say: huh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's the expected behavior, because the comparison is done using string representations, and the function does not recurse down nested arrays. From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php):

> The two values from the *key => value* pairs are considered equal only if *(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2* . In other words a strict type check is executed so the string representation must be the same.

If you tried to intersect with an array with `'key1' => 'Array'`, you'd get the same result because the string representation of an array is always `'Array'`.

[One of the user-contributed notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php#39822), by nleippe, contains a recursive implementation that looks promising (I modified the third line to do string comparison on any non-array values):

```
function array_intersect_assoc_recursive(&$arr1, &$arr2) {
    if (!is_array($arr1) || !is_array($arr2)) {
//      return $arr1 == $arr2; // Original line
        return (string) $arr1 == (string) $arr2;
    }
    $commonkeys = array_intersect(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2));
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($commonkeys as $key) {
        $ret[$key] =& array_intersect_assoc_recursive($arr1[$key], $arr2[$key]);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: I've updated the latter implementation with a more mainstream backwards compatibility http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php#111707.

Comment: Above function worked for me, but I had to remove ampersand to prevent a strict warning in PHP 5.6.30 on Ubuntu 16.04 because of the use of the reference in the assignment in the foreach loop i.e. change `$ret[$key] =& array_intersect_assoc_recursive($arr1[$key], $arr2[$key]);` to `$ret[$key] = array_intersect_assoc_recursive($arr1[$key], $arr2[$key]);`

Comment: the `$ret[$key] =& array_intersect_assoc_recursive...` causes warning `Only variables should be assigned by reference...`.  what could be used instead of ampersand ?

Comment: @T.Todua See my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627076/php-question-how-to-array-intersect-assoc-recursively/65825499#65825499

Comment: @KolaB Your decision is wrong, because the function's response will only record Boolean comparison values, not the actual array values. See my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627076/php-question-how-to-array-intersect-assoc-recursively/65825499#65825499

Answer (score 2):

A function that does what you need:

```
/**
 * Get array intersect assoc recursive.
 *
 * @param mixed $value1
 * @param mixed $value2
 *
 * @return array|bool
 */
function getArrayIntersectAssocRecursive(&$value1, &$value2)
{
    if (!is_array($value1) || !is_array($value2)) {
        return $value1 === $value2;
    }

    $intersectKeys = array_intersect(array_keys($value1), array_keys($value2));

    $intersectValues = [];
    foreach ($intersectKeys as $key) {
        if (getArrayIntersectAssocRecursive($value1[$key], $value2[$key])) {
            $intersectValues[$key] = $value1[$key];
        }
    }

    return $intersectValues;
}
```

Comment: I use `getArrayIntersectAssocRecursive` for array inclusion thanks to `getArrayIntersectAssocRecursive($subArray, $array) == $subArray` but this fails with empty arrays, adding `|| ($value1 == [] && $value2 == [])` to `(!is_array($value1) || !is_array($value2))` solves this issue.

Comment: Note that this intersection operation is not commutative due to `$intersectValues[$key] = $value1[$key]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_key_match_recursive(array $main, array $other, $i = 0, &$result = []) {
    foreach($main as $key => $value) {
        $k = sprintf('%s%s', str_repeat('=', $i), $key);
        if (!isset($other[$key])) {
            $result[$k][] = 'not key';
        }
        if (!is_array($value) && empty($other[$key])) {
            $result[$k][] = 'value empty';
        }
        if (is_array($value) && isset($other[$key])) {
            array_key_match_recursive($value, $other[$key], ++$i, $result);
        }
    }

    //return (bool) !$result;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: An explanation to go along with your answer would be great.

Answer (score -1):

My version based on @BoltClock version:

```
function array_intersect_assoc_recursive($arr1, $arr2) {
    if (!is_array($arr1) || !is_array($arr2)) {
        return $arr1;
    }
    $commonkeys = array_keys($arr1);
    if (!array_key_exists('$', $arr2)){
        $commonkeys = array_intersect(array_keys($arr1), array_keys($arr2));
    }
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($commonkeys as $key) {
        $ret[$key] = array_intersect_assoc_recursive($arr1[$key], array_key_exists('$', $arr2) ? $arr2['$'] : $arr2[$key]);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

I use this code to filter data inside complex array

example:

```
$filter = [
    'channels' => [
        '$' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'type' => 1,
            'count' => 1
        ]
    ],
    'user' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'type' => 1
    ]
];
$data = [
    'user' => [
        'id' => '1234',
        'type' => true,
        'counter' => 14,
    ],
    'filteredField' => 4,
    'channels' => [
        ['id' => '567', 'type' => 'other', 'count' => 1345, 'filteredField' => 5,],
        ['id' => '890', 'type' => 'other', 'count' => 5456, 'filteredField' => 7,],
    ],
];
print_r(array_intersect_assoc_recursive($data, $filter));
```

test online:
https://onlinephp.io/c/3be04

Comment: Your adaptation is not suitable for this question.  In your sample data there are no associative matches between twe two arrays.  It seems you are seeking recursive key-only intersections.  You should have a look at @deceze's answer to [Filter 2D associative array using keys from multiple levels of another 2D associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173705/2943403)