# PHP Associative Arrays Intersection returns two elements instead of one

Tags: php, arrays

I have two associative arrays as following

```
    Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => aaaaaa
            [value] => 11111
            [id] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => dddddd
            [value] => 44444
            [id] => 0
        )

)




Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [value] => 11111
            [description] => aaaaaa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [value] => 222222
            [description] => bbbbbb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [value] => 333333
            [description] => cccccc
        )

)
```

The result I am getting is

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => aaaaaa
            [value] => 11111
            [id] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => dddddd
            [value] => 44444
            [id] => 0
        )

)
```

Noting that `dddd` is available in the first array but not the second.

I am using the `array_intersect_assoc( $array1, $array2 )` function.
Please help. It's not logical at all to return such results

Comment: It is clear what you want achieve here, this fucntion "array_intersect_assoc" calculates the intersection of associative arrays with additional index check. Further more what i see there is multidimensional array, just note

Comment: @mubo he need to get the duplicate record from two arrays

Comment: @sasikanth exactly ! and only the duplicate, maybe it's loosing it since it's a multidimensional arrays comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
$intersect = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, 'compareDeepValue');
 print_r($intersect);

 function compareDeepValue($val1, $val2)
 {
  return strcmp($val1['value'], $val2['value']);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will enable php notices you will see next

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

You can get exhaustive answer about your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627076/php-question-how-to-array-intersect-assoc-recursively)

Good luck!